# GraphET Pharo Smalltalk add milestones overlay

Tags: graph, overlay, smalltalk, composite, roassal

I'm trying to do this diagram using GraphET:

[image: Graph]

The idea is to overlay a single 2DDiagram with milestones, composed of a vertical dotted line and a label located below the baseline.

Looking at the GET code I found several potential ways to do this, maybe building a compositeDiagram or getting the RawView, but my attempts were unsuccessful.

Comment: I'm writing my own solution. You can find it at [http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~NicolasCastro/GET2Extensions](http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~NicolasCastro/GET2Extensions)